# Magento 1.9 is not sending the order confirmation e-mail

Tags: magento-1.9, php, orders, order-email

I'm placing an order in Magento but I never receive the Order confirmation e-mail. I think that crons are set up properly. In : `System->Advanced->System` I set the Heartbeat task schedule (cron syntax) to `*/5****`.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can make sure Crons are working properly by installing [AOE scheduler extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html)

Answer (score 1):

Since **Magento 1.9.1**, the emails are not being sent **directly** during checkout but instead are being queued. The queue is being processed via your Magento cronjob.

I suggest you to install this free extension [SMTP Pro](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html), set the SMTP config  connexion like Gmail for exemple, and **dont forget** to set `Queue Usage` to `never`, save and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

i removed the following mail sending code from Template.php , then i started receiving email when the order is placed by customer or when i click manually send email from the admin panel "Sales/Orders" tab.

Copy Template.php from  **/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php**
 And paste into your local **/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php**

Find below line:

```
if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {
```

and replace with the below line

```
if (!$this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {
```

This work for me.

Comment: This worked for me with Magento ver. 1.9.3.4. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just make a small change in order.php

```
public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

First, create one directory structure on the path below, then copy and paste the file to the path below.

```
public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

Now, change from

```
$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();
```

to

```
$mailer->send();
```

after this your order mail working perfectly.

Comment: No effect... stil not sending e-mail

Answer (score 0):

Check you cron configuration using AOE Scheduler. 
You can download it here - https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler

If all OK, check cron output using AOE.

Last thing - check postfix and sendmail logs. Maybe isn't configured correctly.